# CrossGeeks GoogleClientPlugin overriding OpenUrl for 2 plugins

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, google-client

I am using the CrossGeeks plugins in my Xamarin Forms Cross-platform application for Facebook and Google Authentication. Documentations for both say I should ovverride the `OpenUrl` method in iOS `AppDelegate`. However they have a return value and I dont know how to do both

this is how to do it for facebook:

```
  public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
        return FacebookClientManager.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
    }
```

and the return changes for GoogleClient: `return GoogleClientManager.OnOpenUrl(app, url, options);`

so how can I put them both in the same override method? the second return would be unreachable
is there a way to do this (pseudocode)?

```
if(facebook) {
//facebook
}
else {
//google
}
```

Comment: the method **public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)** returns a bool value. So you can put the judgement in the method.

Comment: And how do I determine which return value I need when opening the url?